# multiple fetch with jpa give MultipleBagFetchException

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

In a spring boot 3.2, I have an entity with many oneToMany relation

```
@Entity
public class Teacher{

    @Id
    private Long teacherId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private Lang lang;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "teacher", orphanRemoval = true, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    private List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "teacher", orphanRemoval = true, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    private List<Domaines> domaines = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "teacher", orphanRemoval = true, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    private List<Note> notes = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

I create a query with @Query annotation i done many fetch and get **MultipleBagFetchException** error.

I tried to use entity graph

```
@EntityGraph(
        type = EntityGraph.EntityGraphType.FETCH,
        attributePaths = {
                "lang",
                "students",
                "domaines",
                "notes"
        }
)
Optional<Teacher> findByTeacherId(Long teacherId);
```

But get the same result

is there a way to get all result in one query without cartesian product?

I can surely do a native query, but i would like to avoid

Comment: Bottom line is you cannot have more than one `List` fetched. Has to be `Set`. Also, `new ArrayList<>()` is anti-pattern. What do you mean `without cartesian product`? I don't remember, but I think native query has same problem.